# Finding JVM crash log in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm encountering a hard JVM crash on my program in NetBeans (when a certain action happens, the program becomes unresponsive, and I must force-close it).

Where can I find the stack trace / error log of this crash, if I run the program from NetBeans?

Comment: I don't think that is a hard crash.  A real hard crash would cause NetBeans to exit.  You wouldn't need to force-close it ... because it would have gone already.  It is more likely some kind of deadlock.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, the program becomes unresponsive, and I have to either stop it in NetBeans, or close it from the task manager.

Comment: The corollary is that the reason you can't find the crash log is that it doesn't exist.  You are looking for the wrong kind of evidence.  What you should be asking is 1) how to force a thread-stack dump of the program instance, and 2) how to attach a debugger to it.